# New to Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle SQL developer on my personal computer.

I want to create my own tables in it and work on them.

But, when I try to make the basic connection, it gives an error below

> "network adapter could not make the connection".

Can someone please give a detailed explanation about how can I create my own tables and what I should do to connect to some database?

Comment: You installed SQLdeveloper alright, did you install Oracle DB as well ? ;)

Comment: @alfasin yupp i did...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install Oracle database to create your own tables. You can download Oracle XE from [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/).

For a detailed explanation about how to connect to a database, [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_connecting.htm#CEGFCEGG) comes first when you google it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for windows user. And assume that you have installed oracle database, as answered.

1. Open cmd: (win+r, input cmd, enter).
2. run command: 
   `sqlplus / as sysdba`
3. create a tablespace: 
   `create tablespace <tablespace-name>`
4. create user: 
   `Create user <username> identified by <password> default tablespace <tablespace-name> quota unlimited on <tablespace-name>;`
5. open oracle sql developer, and add a link with the information in step 4. Link type should be set as local! Link type should be set as local! This may be the direct answer to your question.
6. Now you could run sql shell in sql developer.